# How to create different app themes with AppCompat v7:21 using colorPrimary and colorPrimaryDark

Tags: android, android-styles

I've been looking at different tutorials on how to specify multiple themes so the user can switch themes.

They often say to create different themes like this:

```
<resources>

    <style name="RedTheme">
        <item name="android:background">#FF0000</item>
    </style>

    <style name="BlueTheme">
        <item name="android:background">#0000FF</item>
    </style>

</resources>
```

But when using AppCompat-v7:21, you use `colorPrimary`, `colorPrimaryDark`, etc. to specify app-wide colors. And I haven't found a way to specify different values for these.

I've tried this but it doesn't work:

styles.xml

```
<resources xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <style name="AppTheme.Base" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">    
        <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    </style>

    <style name="BlueTheme" parent="AppTheme.Base">
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/blue</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/dark_blue</item>
    </style>

    <style name="RedTheme" parent="AppTheme.Base">
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/red</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/dark_red</item>
    </style>

</resources>
```

When I specify BlueTheme for my entire app in the manifest, the blue colors are not used.

How do you specify different values for `colorPrimary`, `colorPrimaryDark`, etc. for different styles?

If this isn't possible, is there some kind of work-around for this?

Answer (score 0):

Some methods:

1. You can set themes per activity in manifest:

   ```
   <activity
       android:name=".MainActivity"
       android:label="@string/app_name"
       android:theme="@style/RedAppTheme">
       <intent-filter>
           <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
           <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
       </intent-filter>
   </activity>
   <activity
       android:name=".SecondActivity"
       android:label="@string/title_activity_second"
       android:theme="@style/BlueAppTheme">
   </activity>
   ```
2. You can set theme via java using setTheme(R.style.yourTheme):

   ```
   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

       setTheme(R.style.BlueAppTheme);

       setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
   }
   ```

Check that setTheme is before setContentView, if not the app crash.

If you want that the user select one theme, you can use **sharedpreferences** to store an int value and use setTheme inside of switch.

Answer (score 0):

Hi this are mine pieces of xml values that are working correctly I believe:

colors.xml:

```
<resources>
    <color name="primary">#ffd180</color>
    <color name="primary_dark">#ff9100</color>
    <color name="accent">#ff6d00</color>
</resources>
```

styles.xml:

```
<resources>

    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/ActionBar</item>
    </style>

    <style name="ActionBar" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar">
        <item name="android:background">@color/primary</item>
    </style>

</resources>
```

v21/styles.xml:

```
<resources>

    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/primary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/primary_dark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/accent</item>
    </style>

</resources>
```

This correctly handles primary colors and accent for api 21+ Also you can see that I'm forcefully using `@color/primary` in `styles.xml` and this cannot be done other way since older Apis don't know about what does the `colorPrimary` item means.

Little more from Android guys is[on their site about [Maintaining Compatibility](http://developer.android.com/training/material/compatibility.html#Theme), you only need to know that:

> Note: If your app uses the material theme but does not provide an
>   alternative theme in this manner, your app will not run on versions of
>   Android earlier than 5.0.

And some other details